# Resizing image Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am having issues with resizing my picture. I am trying to resize the image to fit the blue drawing. However the way I am doing it, returns an error.

```
File "gui.py", line 42, in fileDialog
self.display = Label(image=self.photo.resize((800, 600),Image.ANTIALIAS))
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize
```

I am just testing it to see if it fits by doing 800,600 I really don't know.

```
def fileDialog(self):
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select")
    self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text="")
    self.label.grid(column=1, row=2)
    self.label.configure(text=self.filename)
    self.photo= ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = self.filename)
    self.display = Label(image=self.photo.resize((800, 600),Image.ANTIALIAS))
    self.display.grid(row=0)
```

[image: Insert image in blue drawing]

Is there something that I am doing incorrectly? Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

You need to resize the image, not the photoimage.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

filename = 'bell.jpg'
img = Image.open(filename)
resized_img = img.resize((200, 100))

root = tk.Tk()
root.photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
labelimage = tk.Label(root, image=root.photoimg)
labelimage.pack()
```

[image]

To address the new question, you do not have to know the filename at the time of label creation.  The following code produces the same result:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
labelimage = tk.Label(root)
labelimage.pack()

filename = 'bell.jpg'
img = Image.open(filename)
resized_img = img.resize((200, 100))
root.photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
labelimage.configure(image=root.photoimg)
```

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't self.photo contain the photo itself?

Comment: @beloas your self.photo contains a representation of the image, but that does not logically conclude that it can do any given task with it; no matter how you look at it, ImageTk.PhotoImage does not have a resize() method.  ImageTk.PhotoImage can open a filename directly, but it is not designed for image manipulation.  Image is.

Comment: I understand, I just am confused about how I would incorporate that in the filedialog function since self.photo doesn't really hold the image that is selected?

Comment: Please see updated question with screenshot of the blue drawing. I am wanting to fit the image into that area.

Comment: @beloas I'm not really sure what you want me to do here.  I answered your question and you've chosen to ignore the answer... and point me back to the question.  Your code is unchanged as I type this.  ImageTk.PhotoImage does not have a resize() method.  You need to store the image in an Image object if you want to perform manipulations upon it.

Comment: I apologize. My main concern with that is that I really do not know the name of the file unless I click it. Basically I don't want to hardcode it `(img = Image.open('bell.jpg'))`; `filename` does not hold the name of the file?

Comment: @beloas Image does know its filename, ImageTk.PhotoImage does not, but that doesn't really have any relevance to the question at hand.  Why would you have to hardcode the filename?  My example works exactly the same if filename is a variable.  If you don't know how to update a label after it has been created, I've added a second example showing how to do that.