# Tkinter: How do I resize an image to fill its labelframe and have that labelframe fill its column?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a frame with 4 columns. They are not all the same width.

Each column has only a labelframe and each labelframe has only a numpy array image.

I've been trying to find a way to consistently resize the images to take up nearly the whole width of the column but here's the kicker:
Sometimes the labelframes will be empty until images are loaded into them.

So I want to find a way to make my labelframe fill the column width, and then when I load in an image, I want the labelframe to stay the same size and have the image resize itself to fill the labelframe.

I have had some success with carefully hard-coding ratios and offsets, but it keeps breaking and I feel like there's a better way to do this.

Not sure if this is important but currently, I am using `cv2.resize()` to resize the images and I'm using

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(numpy_img))
```

to prepare the array for display.

Comment: If you use `grid` manager then `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` can be applied to `Tk` or `Toplevel` and all `LabelFrame`. This will make them expand.

Comment: @Derek But when I add an image, the labelframe snaps to fit the image size. Plus, even if that weren't so, this isn't enough information because it doesn't address resizing the image correctly.

Comment: You need to supply the minimal working code example. Meanwhile here is a link for image resizing using PIL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749577/resizing-image-python-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Code similar to this has been posted before but I'm unable to find the link so here is code for producing dynamic image resizing using `PIL` and `tkinter`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fido
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Resizable:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("600x400")
        self.master.title("Resize Image Demo")
        self.growCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.growCanvas.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = tk.YES)
        picture = fido.askopenfilename(title = "Choose Image")
        self.image = Image.open(picture)
        self.image_copy = self.image.copy()
        self.background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.label = tk.Label(
            self.growCanvas, image = self.background, borderwidth = 0)
        self.label.bind('<Configure>', self.resizeImage)
        self.label.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = tk.YES, padx = 2, pady = 2)

    def resizeImage(self, event):
        image = self.image_copy.resize(
            (self.master.winfo_width(), self.master.winfo_height()))
        self.newimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.label.config(image = self.newimage)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Resizable(tk.Tk())
    app.master.mainloop()
```